# Javascript Errors on Page

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

Trying to figure out what is causing the javascript errors on this page with no luck. Also it is preventing the other javascripts from executing, i.e. the tabs not being formatted, add to cart button not working.  Any feedback is appreciated, thanks

Comment: element.attachEvent("on" + name, wrapper). This is not a function. You are having this problem

Comment: Your are trying to "attachEvent" on controls through your javascript that is causing the errors, i would recommend you to use the Jquery instead of simple JS, that would be more effective.moreover you can use IE8 built-in script debugger to get the error details.

Comment: If you are using FireFox I suggest you get FireBug it has a great Javascript Debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a conflict between prototype and some jquery library you are trying to use.

Just after add your jquery add this, in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$.noConflict();
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype.js has some problem, try first verify the form id.

```
error: productAddToCartForm is undefined in prototype.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, got me going in the right direction - prototype.js was conflicting with a jquery slider I installed - noConflict will fix this, thanks!